# php mysql insert in table textarea lines

Tags: php, textarea, row, lines

I`am using this form to import keys to database one by one.
How to make the form to import keys from textarea (as lines) and to save them (as line) on table.

This is my code Iam using:

HTML CODE:

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
  <table align="center">
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Product Paket:</td>
      <td><select name="produktid">
        <?php
do {  
?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_Paketa['paketaid']?>"><?php echo $row_Paketa['emripaketa']?></option>
        <?php
} while ($row_Paketa = mysql_fetch_assoc($Paketa));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($Paketa);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($Paketa, 0);
      $row_Paketa = mysql_fetch_assoc($Paketa);
  }
?>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Serial Number:</td>
      <td><textarea cols="45" rows="5" name="seriali" /></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Voucher Number:</td>
      <td><textarea cols="45" rows="5" name="kodiabonimit" /></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Insert record" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>
```

PHP CODE:

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
     $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO products (pid, produktid, seriali, kodiabonimit, data) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, NOW())",
                       GetSQLValueString('', "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['produktid'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['seriali'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['kodiabonimit'], "text")
                       );
  mysql_select_db($database, $ksam);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $ksam) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: Heyy @Matt you can vote up now :)) Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
$codi  = $_POST['kodiabonimit'];    
$serial = $_POST['seriali'];


$text = $codi;
$text1 = $serial;



$itemserial = explode("\n", $serial);
$itemcodi = explode("\n", $codi);

foreach(array_combine($itemcodi, $itemserial) as $text => $text1)
{
//code to insert into database
```

Comment: text and text1 variables i use for encryption method before inserting to database.